# Loading symbols iteratively from several packages

Tags: symbols, luatex, stix

The following does not compile with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Fira Math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}

\title{Untitled}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{$\Sigma$}

$$ \leadsto $$

\end{document}
```

Apparently, the problem is in the missing glyph for `\leadsto` in Fira Math.

As compared to STIX2, this font has superior readability, but does not provide all the characters I am used to.

The question is, can *all* the missing symbols in Fira Math be loaded from STIX2 or elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The only font I know that has a `\rightsquigarrow` symbol U+21DD similar to `\leadsto` is FdSymbol.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[mathrm=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmathfont{FdSymbol}[range=\rightsquigarrow,Scale=1.1]
\setmathfont{Fira Math}[range={}]

\renewcommand{\leadsto}{\rightsquigarrow}

\title{Untitled}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{$\Sigma$}

$\rightarrow\leadsto$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The arrow tip is not exactly the same, though.